# How to distinguish between user input, but allow the application itself to change text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, user-interface

I've got a textbox, which does not allow users to enter "[" and "]" characters. However, I would like to set the text to be a value containing both "[" and "]" by default. How can I go about this? This is my code:

```
TextBox txtEdit = new TextBox();
txtEdit.TextChanged += txtEdit_TextChanged;
txtEdit.Text = "[Test]";

private void txtEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("[") || (sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot enter '[' or ']' characters!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        (sender as TextBox).Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use another event for user input, e.g keyup

Comment: what is the error you are getting...

Comment: I am not getting an error @ShariqueAnsari, however the TextChanged event is being entered when the user selects an item from the ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `TextChanged` Event after you change the `Text` property

```
TextBox txtEdit = new TextBox();
txtEdit.TextChanged += txtEdit_TextChanged;

private void txtEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxYou.Text == txtEdit.Text) 
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("[") || (sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot enter '[' or ']' characters!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        (sender as TextBox).Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not setting the text property manually though, but rather when the user selects an item in the COmboBox (this is an editable ComboBox), I want that item to appear inside the textbox

Comment: It's not really best practice but you could check if the `Text` is in your combobox datasource. If so, leave it, if not, show your messagebox

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please, havent really understood?

Comment: I edited my post to reflect your wishes. If I understand correctly. You want to fill the textbox with the combobox item, but the problem was that the `textchanged` event triggers and refuses the change. Right?

Comment: Thats right. Havent really got what you mean by this though: `if (comboBoxYou.Text == txtEdit.Text) 
    {
        return;
    }`

Comment: Well, it checks if the text in your combobox is the same as in the textbox. If it is it just exits the method without doing anything. You probably don't have [ and ] around your text in the combobox so you might need to use `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` methods on the `comboBox.Text` to get the right comparison

Answer (score 1):

I'd set a `keydown` event for the Textbox.

If you don't want users enetering the '[' and ']' characters, then read in the key character and set `e.Handled = true` if it matches the character you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Toon Casteele is a good solution. Otherwise try adding a boolean to your form and when the user selects a value set it to true and check for the value in the TextChanged event if it is true.

```
private bool IsSelectedItemText; //set it to true when an item is selected
```

And then do following check:

```
if(!IsSelectedItemText)
    //Check for square brackets
else
    //Add text from item
```

Also, and this is not directly related to the question but I strongly suggest that you cast the 'sender' object only once. Complete, the code would look like:

```
private void txtEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

    if(!IsSelectedItemText)
    {            
        if (tb.Text.Contains("[") || tb.Text.Contains("]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot enter '[' or ']' characters!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            tb.Text = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Set text from selected item
    }

    IsSelectedItemText = false;
}
```

Remember to set the boolean-variable to 'true' when an item is selected.

Comment: When not related to the question, post it as a comment please.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with my question

Comment: Sorry, was only trying to help. Added another possible solution to my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If thats what you wanted.

```
private void txtEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
string a = (sender as TextBox).Text.substing(0,1).subsctring;
a = a.Remove(0, 1);
            a = a.Remove(a.Length - 1, 1);
            if (a.Contains('[') || a.Contains(']') )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot enter '[' or ']' characters!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            (sender as TextBox).Text = "[" + a.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "") + "]";

}
```